# How can I pass down format string options from the user to my components?

Tags: rust

I want to have the user decide the formatting of my struct, and just pass it to the struct underneath it.

For example:

```
struct Coordinates {
    x: i64,
    y: i64,
}

impl fmt::Display for Coordinates {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Coordinates(x: {}, y: {})", self.x, self.y)
    }
}

impl fmt::LowerHex for Coordinates {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Coordinates(x: {:x}, y: {:x})", self.x, self.y)
    }
}
```

I want this to work like

```
let c = Coordinates { x: 10, y: 20 };

println!("{}", c);
// => Coordinates(x: 10, y: 20)

println!("{:010x}, c");
// => Coordinates(x: 000000000a, y: 0000000014)
```

I want to have `"{:010x}"` passed directly into `"Coordinates(x: {here}, y: {and here})"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oh, by the way, from the information [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html), I can see that doing `if f.sign_aware_zero_pad() { write!(...) } else { write!(...) }` can do what I want to, but I don't believe that this is the proper way...

Comment: Maybe a look at the source code from rust can help?
https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/num.rs.html#63

Comment: Not sure if I understand. You want to make `println` working dynamically?

Comment: @hellow: Thanks, in that way do I have to do all the re-inventing for the format options I get?

Comment: @Boiethios: Sort of... maybe passing `f` and the value to another formatter could be good enough, like `format!("Coordinates(x: {}, y: {})"), format(f, self.x), format(f, self.y))`. Just can't find out how.

Comment: @Todoroki You can get a callback that take an int and return a formatted string I guess (or that take a formatter and return it with the needed information)

Comment: A callback with signature `Fn(&i64, &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result` would probably the best approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write `self.x.fmt(f)` to forward the call to its inner members reusing the same formatter.

```
use std::fmt;

struct Coordinates {
    x: i64,
    y: i64,
}

impl fmt::Display for Coordinates {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Coordinates(x: ")?;
        self.x.fmt(f)?;
        write!(f, ", y: ")?;
        self.y.fmt(f)?;
        write!(f, ")")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl fmt::LowerHex for Coordinates {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Coordinates(x: ")?;
        self.x.fmt(f)?;
        write!(f, ", y: ")?;
        self.y.fmt(f)?;
        write!(f, ")")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Coordinates { x: 10, y: 20 };

    assert_eq!(format!("{}", c), "Coordinates(x: 10, y: 20)");
    assert_eq!(
        format!("{:010x}", c),
        "Coordinates(x: 000000000a, y: 0000000014)"
    );
}
```

Comment: Oh! You can do that because you're in the same trait! I never came up to that! thank you.